# Denied email permission with Facebook authentication through Owin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

How do I re-ask user to accept email permission after it was denied?

My code is:

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "0000",
    AppSecret = "0000",
    BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
    UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location",
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = context =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
};
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Using this helper class to extract only the info that i need:

```
/* I have taken validation and error handling out */
public static class ExternalLogin
{
    public static ExternalLoginInfo get(IOwinContext context)
    {    
        var auth = context.Authentication;
        var loginInfo = auth.GetExternalLoginInfo();
        var identityInfo = auth.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);      

        return new ExternalLoginInfo { 
            email = loginInfo.Email
           ,name = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Name 
           ,provider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider
           ,user_access_token = identityInfo.FindFirstValue("FacebookAccessToken")
        };
    }
}

public class ExternalLoginInfo
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }    
    public string provider { get; set; }
    public string user_access_token { get; set; }
}
```

When user denies email permission email is set to null.

**oauthcontroller.cs**

```
  public ActionResult callback()
        {          
            var loginInfo = ExternalLogin.get(HttpContext.GetOwinContext());

            /* User denied permission, ask again */
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(loginInfo.email))
            {
                /* Here I can display a message which helps 
                   user understand  why I need hers/his email 
                   and ask to accept permission */
             return View("need_your_email_dude");
            }
           ...
```

But how do I trigger permission form again from need_your_email_dude **view**?